# Setting up a VM for Selenium tests in online TFBuild

Tags: powershell, selenium, azure-web-app-service, tfsbuild, azure-devops

EDIT: I overlooked "Prerequisites for executing build definitions is to have your build agent ready, here are steps to setup your build agent, you can find more details in this blog ." from [these steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/29/testing-in-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-workflows.aspx). I'm currently trying to get that build agent up and running on an Azure VM and will report back.

I'm following [these steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/29/testing-in-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-workflows.aspx) to try and get CD and Selenium tests running through my Visual Studio Online TFbuild. I've had some helpful hints after sending some feedback via email, but I'm still not able to get past the file copy step.

- I've created a Windows 10 Enterprise VM.
- I've correctly set the ip address in my build test machines and am able to RDP into the machine.
- I've successfully (after several attempts) gotten Remote Power shell working (though I'm not 100% certain  winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="Hosted Agent"}'). I got the name from https://{}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentQueue or Build > edit build > General > Default Queue > Manage.
- PS C:\users\cdd\Desktop> winrm quickconfig
  WinRM service is already running on this machine.
  WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
  This seems to be ready after
- PS remoting is not supported when network connection type is public. Please check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/03/setting-network-location-to-private.aspx.
- and echo "setting executionpolicy"
  powershell -command "& Set-ExecutionPolicy -executionpolicy unrestricted -force"
  echo "setting remoting"
  powershell -command "& Enable-PSRemoting -force"

That's a lot of details, but I'm still stuck after that:

Copy started for - '{ip}:5985'
Copy status for machine '{ip}:5985' : 'Failed'
Failed to execute the powershell script. Consult the logs below for details of the error.
Failed to connect to the path \{ip} with the user cdd for copying.System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
For more info please refer to http://aka.ms/windowsfilecopyreadme

I have a few questions:

1. Do I have the correct name of the VM?
2. Do you have steps on how to get the VM setup to allow FileCopy?
3. I'm probably missing something else, I'm not familiar with PowerShell or getting this setup. What can I try to get the path available for my cdd adminstration user that I setup when I created the VM?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To copy files to an Azure VM machine, you should use the "Azure File Copy" step that provided in VSO build definition. It provides detailed setting for you to access to your Azure VM machine.[image]

Comment: It keeps saying it can't find my storage account, that I just created. I can see it by that name in Azure portal. I copied the name from Access Keys > Storage Account Name. Did I miss something?

Comment: I had created the storage account with the resource option, when I tried this again I created the storage account as classic and it found it, but now I'm getting "Connecting to remote server {ip} failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. "

Comment: Can you provide the detailed error message you see?

Comment: I'm trying to setup my own build agent instead of the Hosted Agent. We'll see. Here's the error: Connecting to remote server 23.96.201.234 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.

Comment: Try use HTTPS protocol for WinRM. You can change this testing from "Test\Machines*".

Comment: I tried it and got an error again (sorry I lost that one after trying other things). I'm beginning to wonder if they both need a matching cert setup to be able to communicate.

Comment: Is the error related to the CA of the certificate? If yes, you can check "Skip CA Check" option when you setup the test machines.

Comment: Hello, can you try it again and provide the error message? Also, you can refer to this page for details: https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopy/README.md & https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/releases/m90/Tasks/AzureFileCopy/